# Flip the GraphicsPath that draws the text/string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+, graphicspath

I have this method in my Text Class and I can't seem to flip the whole text.
I am using a Matrix to transform the `GraphicsPath` which is used to draw the string.

Here's the code since I used @Jimi's answer:

```
    public LayerClass DrawString(LayerClass.Type _text, string text, RectangleF rect, Font _fontStyle, Brush brush, float angle, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (StringFormat string_format = new StringFormat())
        {
            SizeF stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, _fontStyle);
            rect.Location = new PointF(Shape.center.X - (rect.Width / 2), Shape.center.Y - (rect.Height / 2));
            GraphicsContainer gc = e.Graphics.BeginContainer();
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            //e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Rectangle.Round(rect));

            RectangleF r = new RectangleF(rect.Location, rect.Size);
            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
            if (text == "" || text == " ")
                path.Dispose(); //Disposes the path to prevent OutOfMemoryExcetption
            else
            {
                path.AddString(text, _fontStyle.FontFamily, Convert.ToInt32(_fontStyle.Style), _fontStyle.Height, new Point(0,0), string_format);
                RectangleF text_rectf = path.GetBounds();
                PointF[] target_pts = {
                            new PointF(r.Left, r.Top),
                            new PointF(r.Right, r.Top),
                            new PointF(r.Left, r.Bottom)};
                //e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Rectangle.Round(r));
                using (Matrix m = new Matrix(text_rectf, target_pts)) 
                using (Matrix rotate = new Matrix())
                using (Matrix FlipXMatrix = new Matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)) 
                using (Matrix FlipYMatrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0))
                using (Matrix TransformMatrix = new Matrix())
                {
                    TransformMatrix.Multiply(m);
                    m.RotateAt(angle, new PointF(0 + (stringSize.Width / 2), +(r.Height * 2)));
                    rotate.RotateAt(angle, new PointF(r.X, r.Y));
                    TransformMatrix.Multiply(rotate);
                    if (flipped)
                    {
                        TransformMatrix.Multiply(FlipXMatrix);
                    }
                    path.Transform(TransformMatrix);

                    if (flipY)
                    {
                        TransformMatrix.Multiply(FlipYMatrix);
                        path.Transform(TransformMatrix);
                    }

                    //Checks if the user wants the text filled or outlined
                    if (!isOutlined)
                        e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Red, path);
                    else
                        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Red, path);
                } 
            }
        e.Graphics.EndContainer(gc);
        }
        this._Text = text;
        this._TextRect = rect;
        this.brush = brush;
        this._Angle = angle;
        return new LayerClass(_text, this, text, rect);
    }
```

> Now the problem is, it goes out the center of the picturebox.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a simpler way to *flip* a `Graphics` object.
Create a [Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) which is the result of the [Matrix multiplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.multiply?view=netframework-4.7.2) of all the transformations that need to be applied to the specified object.

A Matrix transformation can be applied to either the [GraphicsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) object or the `Graphics` object. Or both, when multiple transformation need to be performed sequentially.

The .Net `System.Drawing.Drawing2D` Matrix class does not have a pre-built `Flip` (mirroring) transformation, but this Matrix structure is already well known (I'm not sure this is the reason why there isn't a specific method in the Matrix class):

```
| 1 | 0 | 0 |       |-1 | 0 | 0 |       | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |       | 0 | 1 | 0 |       | 0 |-1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |       | 0 | 0 | 1 |       | 0 | 0 | 1 |

   Identity         Mirror X-Axis       Mirror Y-Axis
    Matrix              Matrix             Matrix
```

You can notice (it's also reported in the Docs) that the 3rd column is always the same, therefore, when building a new Matrix, the 3rd column values are implied and are provided by the Matrix class initialization, so we specify just the elements in the first 2 columns.

Important note, straight from the Matrix class Docs:

> **Caution**:
> The order of a composite transformation is important. In general, rotate, then scale, then translate is not the same as
>   scale, then rotate, then translate. Similarly, the order of matrix
>   multiplication is important. In general, ABC is not the same as BAC

**An example of a string drawn on a `Panel` using the** [GraphicsPath.AddString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.addstring?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath.AddString);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) **method**.
Two Matrix transformations are added to the `GraphicsPath` object:
a `Flip-X` and a `Flip-Y`, which are combined using the `Matrix.Multiply()` method:

The `Flip-X` and `Flip-Y` Matrices are built including the `X` and `Y` translations, applied to the 3rd row of each `Matrix`.
The translation values are determined by the *Canvas* dimensions.
For example, the `Flip-X` Matrix:

With a `[Canvas].Width = 100  =>`:
**Rotation Element** : Rotate the X-Axis 180° (-1 radians) on the origin `Point(0, 0)`.
**Translate Element**: Translate the `X` Position `100` Graphics Units to the right (positive value).

```
| -1  |  0  |  0  |
|  0  |  1  |  0  |
| 100 |  0  |  1  |

   Mirror X-Axis
  Translate X +100
      Matrix
```

---

A visual representation of the effect.
The Controls referenced in the code are the same you can see here (if you need to reproduce it).

[image: Matrix Flip]

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;

bool flipX = false;
bool flipY = false;
bool outlined = false;
float sampleFontEmSize = 28f;
string sampleText = "Sample Text to Flip";
FontFamily sampleFont = new FontFamily("Segoe UI");

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Panel panel = sender as Panel;
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
    using (var format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip | StringFormatFlags.NoWrap))
    {
        format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        path.AddString(sampleText, sampleFont, (int)FontStyle.Regular, sampleFontEmSize, panel.ClientRectangle, format);

        using (var flipXMatrix = new Matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, panel.Width, 0))
        using (var flipYMatrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, panel.Height))
        using (var transformMatrix = new Matrix())
        {
            if (flipX) {
                transformMatrix.Multiply(flipXMatrix);
            }
            if (flipY) {
                transformMatrix.Multiply(flipYMatrix);
            }
            path.Transform(transformMatrix);
            //Or e.Graphics.Transform = TransformMatrix;

            if (outlined) {
                e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.LawnGreen, path);
            }
            else {
                e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Orange, path);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void btnFlipX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    flipX = !flipX;
    panel1.Invalidate();
}

private void btnFlipY_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    flipY = !flipY;
    panel1.Invalidate();
}

private void chkOutlined_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    outlined = chkOutlined.Checked;
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: I'm using checkbox for the flipping, but the text changes it's location when I uses used your snippet and modified the controls.

Comment: @TerribleDog  As in the previous comment. Try to implement this on it's own, using the code shown here. When you have tested how it works, apply these transformations to the code you have. Read the notes and the Docs. These Matrix transformations are stacked. If you don't use them in the right order, they'll probably work in a different way. Also, as always, if your code produces different results, you need to update your question and show what you are actually using, otherwise it's all unclear and can't be fixed.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: I fixed the error Jimi, since I'm drawing the Picturebox, I used the size of the picture box  as the dX and dY for the matrix. Thanks once again @Jimi

Comment: Okay okay Jimi. :)

Comment: The rotation of my text is getting in the way of flipping. They can't coexist  hahaha. I've been fixing this for hours

Comment: I linked those Docs about the Matrix for your advantage. You should read them. One passage, in red background, warns: ***Caution***: *The order of a composite transformation is important. In general, rotate, then scale, then translate is not the same as scale, then rotate, then translate. Similarly, the order of matrix multiplication is important. In general, ABC is not the same as BAC.* Follow the simple example there, with the knowledge that the sequence is relevant. In a previous comment: *These Matrix transformations are stacked...*.

Comment: sorry to bother you and for not updating that I already fixed the issue. you were right, the order of transformations is the problem.

Comment: @TerribleDog  Yes, I saw your other question. I know the Matrices stacking and multiplying is not the easiest thing to understand at first. It needs some hard practice.

Comment: Yes. I'm still bewildered how fixing one could fix another problem in that matrix.