# Behaviour of Graphics.AddRectangle() / Graphics.DrawPath()

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, gdi+, gdi

I attempt to draw lines on specific coordinates using a Graphics.AddRectangle() and Graphics.DrawPath().

The parameters of my Rectangle:

```
Dim objPath As New GraphicsPath
objPath.AddRectangle(New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Width, 1))
```

Then I draw it using DrawPath:

```
objPen.Width = 1
objGraphics.DrawPath(objPen, objPath)
```

I expect a "line" (rectangle) on the top of my graphic having a width of exactly 1px. Result: It draws a line of 2px width.

Demonstration of the 2px width drawing

[image: Demonstration of the 2px width drawing]

What is the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Why are you drawing a rectangle instead of a line? -- Check the `Pen.Alignment` property -- The notes about the Pen here: [Graphics DrawPath produces unexpected results when rendering text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68877110/7444103) may be useful

Comment: @Jimi I was looking for an alternative to `Graphics.AddLine`. It turned out that the use of Pen is the reason for this behavior - I will answer this question myself soon