# Drawing arc with C# using Autocad infos

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I have winform project in c#. There is arc shape created in Autocad. I want to create the same shape on form with the paint event. I get the coordinates, radius and angles infos of the shapes with autocad List command.

The `DrawArc` method takes 4 parameters: 1-The pen. 2-Rectangle to draw in. 3-Start angle. 4-Sweep angle.

I could not match these parameters with the information you see on the right side of the picture below.

This is the shape and infos

[image]

These are my codes:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            float X1 = 73.7153F;
            float Y1 = 36.0911F;
            float X2 = 271.4735F;
            float Y2 = 315.4934F;
            float width = X2 - X1;
            float height = Y2 - Y1;


            // Changes the coordinates Y axis accrording to form coordinates
            Y2 = 36.0911F;
            Y1 = 315.4934F;
            // Create pen.
            Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

            // Create start and sweep angles .
            float startAngle = 195.0F;
            float sweepAngle = 95.0F;

            // Draw arc to screen.
            e.Graphics.DrawArc(blackPen , X1, Y1, width, height, startAngle, sweepAngle);
        }
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Why not look up the specs?? [Autcad](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-30ECFD30-A1D6-4D60-9DD1-B487603F6772-htm.html) clearly states that the points are center, endpoint, start point. DrawArc is quite different: It has a Rectangle to bound the ellipse of which  the arc would be part of. So you will have to use a bit of math..

Comment: The first thing you should do is to transform the coordinates system to the cartesian plane in the 1st quadrant, since you probably have this type of coordinates. See [Coordinate Systems and Transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/coordinate-systems-and-transformations), [Types of Coordinate Systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/types-of-coordinate-systems), [Global and Local Transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/global-and-local-transformations)

Comment: [Graphics.TranslateTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.translatetransform), [Graphics.RotateTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.rotatetransform) and / or use a [Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix) object, which can combine up coordinates translation and rotation at the same time. A few notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53182901/7444103)

Comment: Many thanx for comments. I thought there is easy way for that but i should do some maths