# How do I plot random arrays?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, graphics

I know the basics of arrays and graphics (plotting of graphs, creating trigonometric functions) in NET Framework.
I cannot seem to visualize how I can manage to generate array elements randomly, represented by the bar heights (in white), just like in the image below:

I have only tried the code below and I only get a single number every time I generate a number. What I am expecting is to have 0 to 100 listed in a random order but I cannot do it.

```
Public Class FormSortingAlgorithm
    Dim rnd As New Random()
    Dim nums() As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Private Sub btnGenerate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGenerate.Click
        Dim i As Integer
        ReDim nums(19)
        For i = 0 To 19
            nums(i) = rnd.Next(0, 100)
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnDisplayArray_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayArray.Click
        txtDisplay.Text = nums(j) & nums(i)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What are `i` and `j` in `nums(j) & nums(i)`?

Comment: You've got some great code to look at below, but there really wasn't anything wrong with your code other than the display part. Just change `txtDisplay.Text = nums(j) & nums(i)` to `txtDisplay.Text = String.Join(", ", nums)` to see your random numbers. They were all there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This line: `txtDisplay.Text = nums(j) & nums(i)` won't show the content of your array in a TextBox, just a single glued up number, composed by two elements in the array.
  In case `j` is defined somewhere and it represents a valid index
  You can use [String.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join) to build a string that contains all the elements in a collection using a separator (`vbCrLf` here, since you have a TextBox)

I suggest you replace the array with a `List(Of Integer)`, it's a quite more flexible type of collection. You can add or remove elements when / if required. You can always call its `.ToArray()` method, in case an array is needed, for some reason

- The upper bound of [Random.Next(Int32, In32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next) is excluded from the range.
  To generate values in the range `(0 : 100)`, you have to specify `[Random].Next(0, 101)`

In the example, I'm using a PictureBox to plot the collection of random Integer values.
The world coordinates of the Graphic surface are converted to the Cartesian Plane, 1st quadrant.
The `(0, 0)` vertex is the bottom-left vertex of the canvas (the PictureBox) instead of the upper-left vertex.
If you don't care about this. remove the Matrix object and the `Graphics.Transform = [Matrix]` assignment

About the Matrix used here, see the notes in [Flip the GraphicsPath that draws the text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53182901/7444103)

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Linq

Private Shared ReadOnly rnd As New Random()
Private plotNumbers As List(Of Integer) = Nothing
Private penWidth As Single = 1.0F
Private numOfLines As Integer = 19

Private Sub btnGenerate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGenerate.Click
    ' Generate a new collection of random integers
    plotNumbers = GenerateNumbers(numOfLines)
    ' Show the generated values in a TextBox
    txtDisplay.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, plotNumbers)
    ' Plot the lines in a PictureBox (named PlotSurface)
    PlotSurface.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub PlotSurface_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PlotSurface.Paint
    If plotNumbers Is Nothing OrElse plotNumbers.Count = 0 Then Return

    Dim canvas = DirectCast(sender, Control).ClientSize
    ' Scales the height of the lines to the Height of the Canvas. Remove if not needed
    Dim scaleFactor = canvas.Height / 100.0F
    Dim horzPosition As Single = 1.0F
    Dim line As Integer = 0

    Using pen As New Pen(Color.White, penWidth),
        toCartesianPlane = New Matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, canvas.Height)
        e.Graphics.Transform = toCartesianPlane
        While horzPosition < canvas.Width
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, horzPosition, 0, horzPosition, plotNumbers(line) * scaleFactor)
            horzPosition += penWidth
            line = (line + 1) Mod numOfLines
        End While
    End Using
    e.Graphics.ResetTransform()
End Sub


Private Function GenerateNumbers(numCount As Integer) As List(Of Integer)
    Return Enumerable.Range(0, numCount).Select(Function(n) rnd.Next(0, 101)).ToList()
End Function
```

This is how it works:

[image: Plotting Random Numbers]

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, because you removed all the code and the sample animation